# How to create data types via module

Tags: 7, hooks, nodes

I am writing a module that will create the data types for my site.  I am using hook_node_info to create the type itself, then I am using  field_create_field and field_create_instance to add fields.  field_create_field and field_create_instance are functions, so I am wondering which hook they should go into.  My two best guesses at this point are either hook_node_info or hook_install.  The api seems to indicate hook_install, but I find this confusing.   hook_install happens before hook_node_info, so how can you add fields to a content type that does not exist yet?  Also hook_node_info happens every page load, but hook_install only happens once (at the time that the module is installed.)  Am I creating my content type correctly or am I missing something?

Comment: The short version is: create two modules. One that defines the field, and one that consumes it.

Comment: What's the long version?

Comment: Code, code and more code :) (I'm not trying to be unhelpful by the way, when I get a chance later on I'll try to dig out the relevant links)

Comment: Thanks.  There was another post that recommended using features.  I attempted to use features in the past to do this, but the content types that were produced were un-usable (generated errors when an attempt was made to create content using them.)

Comment: I'm using features extensively with content types without problems.

Comment: Looks like like the Feature Module is the answer.  Anyone want to explain as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of attempting to create your datatype module from scratch, use the Features module to store your content type settings in a feature generated module.  This is faster, but may not cover all of the options that you need (field order, field groups or autotitle.)